# Why axis labels are not removed from the DOM in d3?

Tags: d3.js

I'm implementing a chart using d3 that has a sliding x axis. [Demo](http://codepen.io/moroshko/pen/LxROWQ?editors=0010)

I noticed that the amount of ticks (i.e. the amount of axis labels) keeps growing, meaning that the labels that slide out of the chart are not removed from the DOM.

Why are the old labels stay in the DOM, and how could I fix that?

```js
const timeWindow = 10000;
const transitionDuration = 3000;

const xScaleDomain = (now = new Date()) =>
  [now - timeWindow, now];

const totalWidth = 500;
const totalHeight = 200;
const margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
};
const width = totalWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = totalHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3.select('.chart')
  .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

svg
  .append('rect')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

// Add x axis
const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(xScaleDomain(new Date() - transitionDuration))
  .range([0, width]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

const xAxisSelection = svg
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(xAxis);

// Animate
const animate = () => {
  console.log(d3.selectAll('.tick').size()); // DOM keeps growing!!!

  xScale.domain(xScaleDomain());

  xAxisSelection
    .transition()
    .duration(transitionDuration)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .call(xAxis)
    .on('end', animate);
};

animate();
```

```css
svg {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

rect {
  fill: #fff;
  outline: 1px dashed #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@4.4.1/build/d3.js"></script>
<div class="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Analysis

The axis component will actually *try* to remove the ticks, which are no longer visible. Examining the source code brings up the [line](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/src/axis.js#L92):

```
tickExit.remove();
```

Debugging to this line shows, that the exit selection is correctly calculated, i.e. all exiting nodes are contained in `tickExit`. But the nodes will not be removed as expected, because you have an active transition running on them. The [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_remove) has it:

> [*#*](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_remove) *transition*.**remove**() [<>](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/src/transition/remove.js)
>
> For each selected element, [removes](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_remove) the element when the transition ends, as long as the element has no other active or pending transitions. If the element has other active or pending transitions, does nothing.

---

#### Workaround

One—[admittely hacky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41669741/why-axis-labels-are-not-removed-from-the-dom-in-d3/41674839?noredirect=1#comment70571478_41674839)—workaround could make use of the way D3 fades the ticks, which are no longer visible. This is not very nice, though, because it relies on the inner workings of D3 and might break in the future, should this behavior be altered.

Because [`selection.remove()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_remove) is not that faint hearted, it can be used to take care of the removal instead of using `transition.remove()`. Personally, I would use something along the following lines in your `animate()` function:

```
d3.selectAll(".tick")
  .filter(function() {
    return +d3.select(this).attr("opacity") === 1e-6;
  })
  .remove();
```

Because the axis component will eventually fade all non-visible ticks to an opacity of `1e-6` this can be used to discard those elements. Note, however, that the tick count will at first come up to some value other than the starting value, because the transition to the final opacity will take some time to complete. But, the excess tick count is small and can safely be ignored.

Have a look at the following working demo. In this example, the tick count will increase from the initial 10 to 19 and subsequently stay at this value.

```js
const timeWindow = 10000;
const transitionDuration = 3000;

const xScaleDomain = (now = new Date()) =>
  [now - timeWindow, now];

const totalWidth = 500;
const totalHeight = 200;
const margin = {
  top: 30,
  right: 50,
  bottom: 30,
  left: 50
};
const width = totalWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = totalHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3.select('.chart')
  .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight)
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

svg
  .append('rect')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height);

// Add x axis
const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(xScaleDomain(new Date() - transitionDuration))
  .range([0, width]);

const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

const xAxisSelection = svg
  .append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
  .call(xAxis);

// Animate
const animate = () => {
  console.log(d3.selectAll('.tick').size()); // DOM keeps growing!!!
  d3.selectAll(".tick")
    .filter(function() {
      return +d3.select(this).attr("opacity") === 1e-6;
    })
    .remove();

  xScale.domain(xScaleDomain());

  xAxisSelection
    .transition()
    .duration(transitionDuration)
    .ease(d3.easeLinear)
    .call(xAxis)
    .on('end', animate);
};

animate();
```

```css
svg {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

rect {
  fill: #fff;
  outline: 1px dashed #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div class="chart"></div>
```

---

Anything below is my take on the comments to issue [#23 *"Axis labels are not removed from the DOM"*](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/issues/23#issuecomment-272911905) opened by OP for the d3-axis module, which contains some really good points.

The [comment](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/issues/23#issuecomment-272911905) by Mike Bostock provides a more in-depth look at the concurring transitions on the same element, which will eventually prevent the removal of the ticks:

> The problem is that when the *end* event for the parent G element is dispatched, the axis has not yet removed the old ticks. The ticks are removed by [*transition*.remove](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/README.md#transition_remove), which listens for the [*end* event](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/blob/master/src/transition/remove.js) on the tick elements. The *end* event for the G element is dispatched prior to the *end* event for the tick elements, so you are starting a new transition that interrupts the old one before the axis has a chance to remove the old ticks.

The real gem whatsoever is to be found in the [comment](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/issues/23#issuecomment-272799031) by @curran, who suggested to use `setTimeout(animate)`. This is brilliant and, as far as I know, the only non-intrusive, non-hacky solution to this problem! By pushing the `animate` function to the end of the event loop, this will defer the creation of the next transition until after the actual transition has had the chance to clean up after itself.

---

And, to wrap up this theoretical discussion, the probably best conclusion to your actual problem seems to be Mike Bostock's:

> If you want a real-time axis, you probably don’t want transitions. Instead, use d3.timer and redraw the axis with every tick.

Comment: Thanks for spending the time to debug this, but your proposed solution feels very hacky.

Comment: @MishaMoroshko As a token of appreciation, don't simply say "thanks": instead of that, upvote the answer, as I just did. And, despite you saying that the answer is a hack (btw, my solution would be exactly the same, using filter and an attribute), you have to agree that altocumulus gave you the correct explanation of the problem (exactly like Bostock's explanation: https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/issues/23#issuecomment-272911905).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thank you for supporting this answer! Although I am going to stand by my analysis, I think OP is right, that the suggested solution in fact is a rather hacky workaround. I'll give him that! I have further elaborated on some of the facts brought up in the issue opened by OP as they provide some very interesting points and an elegant, totally different solution. The real value of this kind of seemingly simple questions is, that they prove intricate upon closer inspection, and yet provide the deepest insights.